# How does this recursion work & how do i get it to print out the root?

Tags: java, recursion, tostring

So I've made an implementation of a BST

```
private String toStringHelper(Node node) {


            if (node == null) {
                return "";
            }
            if (node.left != null) {
                System.out.println(node.left.value);
                toStringHelper(node.left);

            }

            if (node.right != null) {
                System.out.println(node.right.value);
                toStringHelper(node.right);

            }


            return "";
        }
```

I want to use recursion. The problem is that it won't print the element that is my root, otherwise it seems to work (Start of Edit).
when inserted following values 100, -12, -13, -1, 0, 12, 10, 123, 122, 124. It returns them in the following order:
-12
-13
-1
0
12
10
123
122 
124 Which clearly is not ordered at all.
(End of Edit)

The thing is that I'm not entirely sure on how the recursion part works and I would like to have this explained so that I also can get method to print out the root in the appropriate place.

Comment: what's the point of returning "" ?

Comment: you never print the value of node...

Comment: String toStringHelper() I couldn't return nothing, And I couldn't make method void. And since i print out the values in System.out.println(node.left.value); i didn't find it useful to print it twice. 
I'm aware that it is "weird" practice. How would you change the method?

Comment: Why can't the method be void?

Comment: Oh... i realized that in my trial and error phase i wrote  
return toStringHelper(node.right); which forced me to return the correct data type. thank you!

Comment: Write a linked list. That is, the same principle as this, but with only one child per node. Use recursion. Make sure you understand it. Once you understand recursion for that simpler case, a tree should be much easier.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you pass it the beginning node and then print the left and right sub-trees. You need to print out the value at the node being passed as a param to the method, and then call the method on the node's left and right children

```
private String toStringHelper(Node node) {

        if (node == null) {
            return "";
        }
        //print the value of the current node
        System.out.println(node.value);
        if (node.left != null) {
            //System.out.println(node.left.value);
            toStringHelper(node.left);

        }

        if (node.right != null) {
            //System.out.println(node.right.value);
            toStringHelper(node.right);

        }


        return "";
    }
```

**EDIT:** Moved the print statement to after the null check per OLE V.V.'s correction

Comment: I make the call from

public int leaves(){
            return leavesHelper(root);
    }

where root is stored in a field as the first element inserted to the tree

Comment: You will want to have the null check *before* printing `node.value` — not after. :-)

Comment: @ Ole V.V. That doesn't seem to change much.
Either it prints out the root in the beginning or at the end.

Comment: @L.Emil, can your root be null if the tree contains no elements at all? If so, you need to have the null check before printing `node.value`. If not, you don't need the first null check at all.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer to the original question is very simple and already pointed out by other posters, I would like to provide a more elaborate answer about recursive tree traversal maybe it will be helpful for future visitors of this post.
There are many different ways of tree traversal, some of them are "naturally" recursive, some of them are not. (See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for more details.) The below code illustrates pre/in/post order depth-first and breadth-first search based on the code in the OP.
Due to practical limitations of recursion (stack overflow), both depth-first and breadth-first should be implemented with loops, using a stack or queue as the underlying data structure, unless the implementation is tail recursive and the platform can optimize it to a loop, but Java compiler does not support that.
In the code below I bring recursive examples, because the original question about recursion, not tree traversal.

```
// depth first pre-order
// root
// left child
// left child of left child
// right child of left child
// right child
// left child of right child
// right child of right child
private String toStringHelperDepthFirst(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }
    System.out.println(node.value);
    toStringHelper(node.left);
    toStringHelper(node.right); 
}

// depth first in-order
// left child of left child
// left child
// right child of left child
// root
// left child of right child
// right child
// right child of right child
private String toStringHelperDepthFirst(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }
    toStringHelper(node.left);
    System.out.println(node.value);
    toStringHelper(node.right); 
}

// depth first post-order
// left child of left child
// right child of left child
// left child
// left child of right child
// right child of right child
// right child
// root
private String toStringHelperDepthFirst(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return "";
    }
    toStringHelper(node.left);
    System.out.println(node.value);
    toStringHelper(node.right); 
}

// breadth-first
// root
// left child
// right child
// left child of left child
// right child of left child
// left child of right child
// right child of right child
private void toStringHelperBreadthFirst(Node node) {
    if(node != null) {
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(node);
        breadhFirst(queue);
    }
}

private <E> void breadthFirst(Queue<E> queue) {
    if(queue.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    Node node = queue.pop();
    System.err.println(node.value);
    if(node.left != null) {
        queue.add(node.left);
    }
    if(node.right != null) {
        queue.add(node.right)
    }
    breadhFirst(queue);
}
```